# find the default AlertDialog windowBackground color/drawable

Tags: android, material-design

I'm implementing a widget which can draw a "blanking" fill behind a popup. I would like this fill to be the *same* transparent black as the one used in the default Android `AlertDialog`.

It's easy enough for me to guess, to use a color picker and estimate. But what I'd really like is to know if there is, somewhere, defined in the android codebase an `android.R.color.dialogWindowBackground` or some such value.

I've done some sleuthing, but to no avail.

The source for AppCompat's `AlertDialog` specifies the theme: `R.attr.alertDialogTheme`. But going through the appcompat source repo, I find styles that are close, but not helpful, such as https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles_base.xml

I've also pored through the colors.xml, etc files and I simply can't find where the AlertDialog's windowBackground is defined.

I know this is sill, I can just run with something arbitrary like #77000000, but I'd like it to be the *correct* dialog window background color.

EDIT:
I've tracked Dialog window background down to a shape drawable:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/drawable/dialog_background_material.xml

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:inset="16dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        <solid android:color="?attr/colorBackground" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

But, how do I resolve the `?attr/colorBackground` value?

Comment: How did you solved it? Or is it still open?

Comment: Nope! I ended up swallowing my pride and hard coding it, but if anybody figures it out (or if I figure it out) I'll post it here.